# How to access list of Map in sightly aem 6.2

Tags: aem, htl

Currently I had a requirement to access the elements of Map from List. Please see the below sample code snippet.

```
List<Map> listOfMap = new Hash();

Map hmap1 = new HashMap();
hmap1.put("name","Rob");
hamp1.put("class","I");

Map hmap2 = new HashMap();
hmap2.put("subjects","{subject1:Maths, subject2:Englsih}");
listOfMap.add(hamp2);
```

Now in sightly I have to access and display this map elements from list.
Can any one suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to expose the list via an [Use-Object](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scripting/scripting-htl.html#sling-specific-use-api-extensions) (Sling Model, POJO or Javascript). Then you can iterate items using `data-sly-list`, for example:

```
<ul data-sly-use.logic="..." data-sly-list.listItem="${logic.list}">
    <li>${listItem.size} items:
        <ul data-sly-list.mapItem="${listItem.keySet}">
            <li>${mapItem} - ${listItem[mapitem]}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```